# Background repeat with limit

Tags: android, background

I have ListView. I would like to fill each row of ListView with a background from left to x% ...

So what I want is:

1. Item - 50% of background is colored
2. Item - 20% of background is colored
3. Item - 90% of background is colored

Is it possible to this?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible out of the box. But I think you can archive is with a little trick.

You have to define a custom view for you rows. This view has a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as root element on which you can set the background color you want to have.

You then add another view element to the root element which covers a part of the root element. The background color of this element should be set to black and should be aligned to the right. The [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) provides many attributed you can use to arrange the elements.

Furthermore you have to write a custom adapter which handles the creation of the single list items views. When you override the [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method where the view elements for each single row are created and inflated to the ListView, you calculate and set the width of the "cover"-element in such a ways that it covers a part of the root element.

The difficult part will be to calculate the width of the cover-element so that the rest of the root element which is not covered and still visible correspond to the percentage you want it to have.

Here you find a [short tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) about how to implement a custom Adapter with a custom view for the list items.

Comment: I've tried it... I have managed to do something like this. But what bothers me is that I can't set the percentages to width of the layout... Any workaround?

Comment: No I think you have to do the calculation on your own. When I rethink about your problem the LinearLayout might be a better solution for you. It provides an attribute called 'weight'. With this attribute you can define a size ratio between the elements within a LinearLayout. So if you've got two elements and set the weight for the first element to 1 and for the second to 2 then the first will take 1/3 and the second 2/3 of the available space. It shouldn't be to hard to calculate the % to such a ratio. But be aware to set the width of both elements to 0 otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yup .. figured that out... One more qestion ... I have to set layout_weight from the code... How can I do that?? This is what I have already (link to layout) `RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)currentView.findViewById(R.id.timmer);`

Comment: You can use the weight attribute only with a LinearLayout not with a RelativeLayout. The layout_weight must be set on the elements within the LinearLayout. Check [this Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d45c5ba63c9f8e9/8e0f4df1928b6863?show_docid=8e0f4df1928b6863&pli=1) to see how to set the weight.

Comment: Great! Managed to combine your help, Google and myself and have done exactly what I wanted. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by the concept of custom layouts. This is a [good article](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) for to learn more. Also, I think you need to go through the [NotePad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) in Android official site.